# How to create a striped richtextbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I need to display text in a RichtTextBox with a green striped background. This means, the first line has a white background-color, the second has a green background-color, the third has white, the next green again etc.

How can I implement this?

The only way I imagine at the moment is setting the color for every textline. But I would have to fill each line with spaces to get whole lines. This way seems to be bad practice to me.

I think about something like OnPaint event, etc. where I can set the background color for every line before text is displayed.

If there is another TextControl that can handle my problem or I have to implement an own control this is an acceptable solution, too. Just give me some hint.

P.S.: I'm using .Net2.0.

Comment: An idea is to have the RTB transparent, and make your pattern behind, maybe using a custom panel on which the RTB is docked.

Comment: It might not be the most practical depending on your requirements for lines (that's why I didn't post an answer).

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve this would be to use the open source http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/ project.  Another SO user asked how to alternate row colors with this particular tool: [Alternate row coloring in Scintilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302165/alternate-row-coloring-in-scintilla)

If you're not opposed to paying for it the WPF [Actipro Syntax Editor](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/dotnet/wpf/syntaxeditor/default.aspx) supports this functionality though I'm not certain the WinForm version does.

A final option would be to use some code from [#Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) or the WPF [AvalonEdit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx)